# ActivityNative has leaked IntentReceiver android.media.MediaPlayerthat was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using android inbuilt media player to play the file from url, it is playing well but at certain point it throws the following error,

```
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109): Activity naapiptv.sazpin.com.fragments.VideoActivityNative has leaked IntentReceiver android.media.MediaPlayer$1@42966010 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity naapiptv.sazpin.com.fragments.VideoActivityNative has leaked IntentReceiver android.media.MediaPlayer$1@42966010 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:795)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:596)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1351)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1331)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1325)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:423)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDisplay(MediaPlayer.java:718)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:242)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:54)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:495)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:597)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:242)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:7544)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1039)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1211)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4353)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:760)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:573)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:746)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-21 23:22:33.587: E/ActivityThread(9109):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not using any `broadcastreciever` at all, it's very strange for me, please somebody help me who might gone through this problem. Thanks in advance